# Network Security on Virtual Folder

Tags: security

How do you implement security features in a virtual or physical folder which is exposing all the files inside it?

Comment: Well you can password protect the folder

Comment: As @NadirLatif said you can password protect the folder, but if you had mentioned more details like where is your folder, environment and your need to protect folder, there is a good chance of getting helpful answers.

Comment: Is your folder accessible over the internet ?. Can you describe your environment and your need for protecting the folder